3D heat transfer of fin using average temperature
I am solving heat transfer problem in 2D rectangular fin along x direction.
Fin is attached at wall with T_w, and exposed to air with T_inf.
The equation will be 2D laplace's equation
$$
0 = \nabla^2 T
$$
where
$$
\nabla = \frac{\partial T}{\partial x}e_{x}+\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}e_{y}
$$
at $x = 0, T = T_w.$ (wall)
at $x = L$, fin tip is insulated ($\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}=0$
y directional boundaries is convective, and dimension of y is quite smaller than x.
I wanted to get average temperature variation along x. I found a analytic solution about similar problem, however, it is quite complicated. Is there any easier solution to make problem more simple?

So are you doing 3D or 2D?

I think if you assume constant temperature in the fin at $x$ (no variation through fin thickness, along $y$ if I understand it correctly), you might reduce the problem into 1D and get quite decent approximate solution.
